# Make setTimeout infinite

Tags: javascript

I have a code

```js
changeSlide(1, $(".slideshow img"));


function changeSlide(i, items) {

  setTimeout(function() {
  var currentItem = items.eq(i);
  var prevItem = items.eq(i-1);
  prevItem.css("left", -prevItem.width());
  currentItem.css("left", 0);
    if(i < items.size()-1)
      changeSlide(i+1, items);
      console.log(i)
    },
  3000);
};
```

This code changes pictures in slide-show for the number of pictures, and then stop. I would like to make it infinite. So when it reach the last one, it will start from the first one again

Comment: check `setInterval` function

Comment: @Gonzalo.- No, don't use `setInterval` here

Comment: You have `if(i < items.size()-1)` now. What could you do `if(i == items.size()-1)` to start over?

Comment: Your code reaches the "end" by `if(i < items.size()-1)`. So just add an `else` condition and make it do what you want in there.

Comment: Btw, I'd suggest passing `0` for `i` on the initial call, and remove the `+1`/`-1` offset everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a way to reset `i` to zero whenever it reaches `items.length`. There are multiple ways to do this. Try changing:

```
changeSlide(i+1, items);
```

to:

```
i = (i + 1) % items.length;
changeSlide(i, items);
```

`%` will loop `(i + 1)` back to 0 once it reaches `items.length`. And of course, get rid of the:

```
if(i < items.size()-1)
```

if statement. You don't need it anymore.

Comment: I don't know if you can see all the times I edit my answer, but sorry if you can. I seem to always see a way to be more clear after I click submit.